# Executor service not shutting down properly while using it with Completable future

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

im executing three tasks asynchronously

```
  CompletableFuture<IStoryDetail> iStoryDetailCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->storyRepository.getStoryDetails(id));
 CompletableFuture<List<Comment>> iCommentFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> commentRepository.getComments(id));
 CompletableFuture<List<Images>> iImageFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> imageRepository.getImagesByStoryId(id));
```

after that im joining all these Tasks

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(iCommentFuture, iStoryDetailCompletableFuture, iImageFuture)
          ;
```

this seems to work fine but when i decide to run the Completable future in a Executor service

```
  @Autowired
  ICommentRepository commentRepository;

  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);




CompletableFuture<IStoryDetail> iStoryDetailCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->storyRepository.getStoryDetails(id),executorService);
     CompletableFuture<List<Comment>> iCommentFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> commentRepository.getComments(id),executorService);
     CompletableFuture<List<Images>> iImageFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> imageRepository.getImagesByStoryId(id),executorService);



iStoryDetailCompletableFuture.thenApply(story -> objectMap.putIfAbsent(story.getClass().getName(),story));
  iCommentFuture.thenApply(comments -> objectMap.putIfAbsent(Comment.class.getName(),comments));
  iImageFuture.thenApply(images -> objectMap.putIfAbsent(Images.class.getName(),images));

   CompletableFuture.allOf(iCommentFuture, iStoryDetailCompletableFuture, iImageFuture).thenRun(() -> executorService.shutdown())
      ;
```

the executor service doesn't seems to shutdown correctly , further request to the controller is getting blocked, what am i missing here thanks for the help in Advance

after removing    thenRun(() -> executorService.shutdown()) it seems to work fine , but how to shut down Exceutorservice properly

Comment: You're not actually spawning multiple threads per request like that are you? As some sort of "multi threading performance increase" trick? This is for testing and you know that this kind of code would be wrong to use for anything real?

Comment: yes i was studying completable future so what seems to be the issue here

Comment: You don't need Spring to study `CompletableFuture`. It just adds unnecessary mess to the mess that is CF itself. You can shut down the executor after the `allOf`, you don't need `thenRun()`.

Comment: thenRun(() -> executorService.shutdown()) this seems to be the problem , how to shutdown the executor service properly

Comment: Although if you intend to use that approach, it makes more sense to keep an executor service alive as long as the service is up, so no reason to shut it down, just make it an instance variable.

Comment: `shutdown()` will prevent adding new tasks to executor, and will wait until all currently added tasks are finished. Since `() -> es.shutdown()` is a task in itself, you enter a kind of infinite process, where shutdown task will stop until shutdown task is finished. See the problem here? You can use `ExecutorService::shutdownNow`, but better not to actually shut it down until your app still works.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov from [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--): **This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution.**

Comment: I don't understand the problem description of the question. You are saying "further request to the controller is getting blocked", but what did you expect? After shutting down the executor service, it doesn't accept new tasks. That's the purpose of shutting down.

Comment: @Holger, yes, you're right. Neither of the shutdown methods wait for anything, I was misremembering things.

Answer (score -2):

shutdown() waits for any existing managed threads to complete. If you don't care if threads it's managing complete, then use shutdownNow().

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--): **This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution.**